# ui select ui-select-choices using array in each item rather than plain text

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I want to use ui select for array inside json items:

I have used ui select in html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 pad-left-right-0 filter">
    <span>Labels</span> 
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="labels.selected" ng-change="refreshData()" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match >{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data | filter: $select.search">
         <div ng-bind-html="item.labels | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select> 
</div>
```

I json containing array in each array element

```
{data: [{
    "developer": "dev",
      "team": "MP",
      "qa": "dev",
      "pm": "dev",
      "jTicket": {
        "jId": "test",
        "jUrl": "jurl",
        "issueType": "Story",
        "jSummary": "test"
      },
      "mr": {
        "number": 25767,
        "title": "test",
        "url": "url",
        "links": [],
        "screenShotLinks": [
          "url_here"
        ],
        "testLinks": [],
        "description": "",
        "labels": ["label 2", "label 5", "label 8"]
      }
    }]}
```

I want to populate ui select ui-select-choices using labels [] in each item in data json. But no label is getting populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are notegetting lables because **lables** key is not on the main node. Its inside the **mr** object. Rather you can use it like this,

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.mr.labels | highlight: $select.search"></div>
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: <div ng-bind-html="item.mr.labels | highlight: $select.search"></div>
This adds [object object] to the select choices. as item.mr.labels is an array

Comment: add the another ng-repeat for labels as well.

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 pad-left-right-0 filter">
    <span>Labels</span> 
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="labels.selected" ng-change="refreshData()" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match >{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in data | filter: $select.search">
         <div ng-repeat="label in data.pr.labels" ng-bind-html="label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select> 
</div>`

It solved the issue but ui-select-match dosent show any value when I select any label.

Comment: Because $item doesn't understand labels.selected , its not array. The actual array is data.pr.labels.

Comment: What should I use instead $item

Comment: $item is ok, use ng-model="data.pr.labels.selected" instead of 
ng-model="labels.selected"

Comment: ng-model="labels.selected" is another array in my controller which is being used to filter the list. Now the issue is I want to display the selected label, and it should get pushed in ng-model array which is labels.selected